# show collections and db.getCollectionNames() is displaying nothing but there is a collection present in the database

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, crud, mongo-shell, mongodb-compass

In my mongoDB compass there is a collection in database but show collections and db.getCollectionNames() in mongosh is not showing anything
[image of mongoDB compass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nwr45.png)
[image of mongosh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70Otc.png)

I want the collection to be displayed on mongosh

Comment: The database name is `personsDB`, but in mongo shell it's `personDB`, missing an `s`